# Return null json requests post method

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to simulate a search on a website. I tracked and found that the website uses post method and this is my attempt

```
import requests

sToken = '''03AGdBq25wTuQvHHSU_HF2WoS6DJZbeh9ajHUOQeOMPAFZtLTANYghGsghuvYIEN5ibr3NZpB90FSKbJI7DSgymFsck91PJ2OQ8X_IN77X6KC0gVCjS4iR6Y22UAtYqLdsXwciZLhRY4frXnbqJZXlgPEKK5GgrlgEvxobJLAZQDoiew3hHOCx1Xue-rcjZuW6IGHsnjs15-NaBrVTxAqbn5CWR4O_r529TMm4m4J6112EhiCpt55S-Q7QVv0ZeTc3Hj8IvOtVhhR6DV0LEmlOcFLoX0ZQuxZ-f6IRwzQNC2GA-iijQ2G2Jvo1UHxnFWIBl5PUvCrCz4e-Ls69aNxMm11QToRl2zkHXxGjJHmojJwT2u3wtaRuX0xRuSlfQPRV9_Jfwf5Eb8KBJ5qGjyEMQyR_HQmxuze5aU7zK7o1GD69ioSWvDl3OCulZo_sc4QcrixkYCGyXFSK3f7I564D8b-Xd8HI7j_76g'''
sVerification='''CfDJ8KYexE-JuUdFv8XKqnZO6wgTYY0hx8JdeirHBUgOs3orS5WyDId3TbriUpQetxGVIWp4l6G8aliDUtH1bW9j5rbtCE6GWD7tUSAJqngcpfNOHTJDGHMOELBX54dGTTYAfZyUtrxzcg67m_WR5RoPULE'''


url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'
payload = {
    'CivilId':'278071306337',
    'Token': sToken,
    'InquiryType':2,
    '__RequestVerificationToken': sVerification,
    }

response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
print(response.text)
```

The response is OK and I could get back a response but the json is null. I just got headers and the token used, but not the result of the search
The result looks like that

```
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "",
  "files": {},
  "form": {
    "CivilId": "278071306337",
    "InquiryType": "2",
    "Token": "03AGdBq25wTuQvHHSU_HF2WoS6DJZbeh9ajHUOQeOMPAFZtLTANYghGsghuvYIEN5ibr3NZpB90FSKbJI7DSgymFsck91PJ2OQ8X_IN77X6KC0gVCjS4iR6Y22UAtYqLdsXwciZLhRY4frXnbqJZXlgPEKK5GgrlgEvxobJLAZQDoiew3hHOCx1Xue-rcjZuW6IGHsnjs15-NaBrVTxAqbn5CWR4O_r529TMm4m4J6112EhiCpt55S-Q7QVv0ZeTc3Hj8IvOtVhhR6DV0LEmlOcFLoX0ZQuxZ-f6IRwzQNC2GA-iijQ2G2Jvo1UHxnFWIBl5PUvCrCz4e-Ls69aNxMm11QToRl2zkHXxGjJHmojJwT2u3wtaRuX0xRuSlfQPRV9_Jfwf5Eb8KBJ5qGjyEMQyR_HQmxuze5aU7zK7o1GD69ioSWvDl3OCulZo_sc4QcrixkYCGyXFSK3f7I564D8b-Xd8HI7j_76g",
    "__RequestVerificationToken": "CfDJ8KYexE-JuUdFv8XKqnZO6wgTYY0hx8JdeirHBUgOs3orS5WyDId3TbriUpQetxGVIWp4l6G8aliDUtH1bW9j5rbtCE6GWD7tUSAJqngcpfNOHTJDGHMOELBX54dGTTYAfZyUtrxzcg67m_WR5RoPULE"
  },
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Content-Length": "708",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.27.1",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-624451fc-6e6add4515bc5d1b413838bb"
  },
  "json": null,
  "origin": "41.237.210.244",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

note that part

```
"json": null,
```

I expect the url to return json that has the string `message` that contains the desired result

I could reach a point that enables me to get the desired result with the following code

```
import requests

cookies = {
    '.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.d9_uhBsXXoI': 'CfDJ8KYexE-JuUdFv8XKqnZO6wjmpfNzm7AIrby7w5RpXYO1XaKtCFOGGQ96YjD5Bcr1O2mEo-FpD4Tys0bSYNvrzXdZfhK2Nj8V2DmuBWFK-g2OjU-koph4q2K5QqkHSZ1iyBWFRm82d6uPjgnZI_ueNjE',
    'BIGipServerE-Service-WEB-APP': '187505580.47873.0000',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
}

data = {
    'CivilId': '278071306337',
    'Token': '03AGdBq27dRjCS0ziDuLKZbICeGo3VqXrV36Y9NhQTF3BWTMC4R3liokPucTiJ0GrcM5kdf4Awk2tiY87uxhdgPphU_NZ5tHx1DU8qMc82qsEJlNCZydvDNwSVt4Akc2yRt5XHOKozftETs9UO2vnLCUgZFNAR7j7sO6SDvuD6N5tdKu77lI8VM4aNvoutHhg0psV2njysbXQMI2pZW7U3Ky27Rw8VAr88o2am8fhpSTisdvY1Zx8TQ8m1L8_IRwVfXSqUDXsTROlPv7H0xEPkUvu81h4WE0sTTw3xCY7HpxmThIBfp-duGtdKtDAi6GiKnd51cAhL3uwAUWxSp0WbFCwLHte_GrVpXUmHYKeRFz5Y-84YXG1vCHUYv-Cp65_nFWp7CyDslvBqJlCdtK45H6L4EyLfaD6G6VUPv-HxOYcD5kZfSh47CKVfLiB_vPCpmCEs7MUAmGUKo0Q19eDppU-FUPKXfs60OQ',
    'InquiryType': '2',
    '__RequestVerificationToken': 'CfDJ8KYexE-JuUdFv8XKqnZO6wi1a2H7xXZBfeIVmwF-9lbwdBqw9VcMXErc7qC8paEuzbnIGaH7z1n27CDmd2NsGqxu8hblfZ7gYfEhrBUM4TxaGxeTacgbs4f_JxJVZVKQ3yvrYS4p5PHZ1ZToFRyh9lk',
}

response = requests.post('https://services.paci.gov.kw/card/search', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)
print(response.text)

with open('Output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(response.text)
```

But how I generate the cookies and tokens with the code itself?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a query? What should I be searching for?

Comment: It is simply search process. Go to this url `https://services.paci.gov.kw/card/search` and type the number in the search box `278071306337` then finally click on the button. The result below the button is the required result.

Comment: I keep getting this:
 حسب سجلاتنا ، البطاقة التي بحوزتك منتهية الصلاحية ولايوجد طلب تجديد ، لذا يرجى إتخاذ الإجراءات اللازمة نحو تجديدها ، مالم يكن قد قمتم بطلب ذلك خلال الأيام السابقة ، وفي هذه الحالة يرجى إعادة المحاولة لاحقا

Comment: Yes, this is the result. But note that the cookies and other tokens are taken manually and I would like to make it dynamically

Comment: I have put an answer (but not an answer). It is my latest try to solve the problem)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer in fact, but my latest try where I tried to create variables for cookies and tokens (but doesn't return the expected result). But I share the code so as to have a look and test (maybe you can find out the real problem)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

from requests_html import HTMLSession

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0',
}

url = 'https://services.paci.gov.kw/card/inquiry?lang=ar&serviceType=2'
s = HTMLSession()
#s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(url, headers=headers)

r.html.render(sleep=5)
resp = r.html.html

#resp = r.text

#s.get('https://services.paci.gov.kw/card/inquiry?lang=ar&serviceType=2')
cookies = s.cookies
cookies_dic = cookies.get_dict()

AspNetCore = cookies_dic['.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.d9_uhBsXXoI']
BIGipServerE = cookies_dic['BIGipServerE-Service-WEB-APP']

print(cookies_dic)
print('=' * 50)
print(AspNetCore)
print('=' * 50)
print(BIGipServerE)
print('=' * 50)

# print(resp)

soup = bs(resp, 'html.parser')
vToken = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': '__RequestVerificationToken'})
print(vToken['value'])
print('=' * 50)

iToken = soup.find('input', attrs={'id': 'Token'})
print(iToken['value'])
print('=' * 50)

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
}
# .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.d9_uhBsXXoI
cookies = {
    '.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.d9_uhBsXXoI': AspNetCore,
    'BIGipServerE-Service-WEB-APP': BIGipServerE,
}

data = {
    'CivilId': '287061510398',
    'Token': iToken['value'],
    'InquiryType': '2',
    '__RequestVerificationToken': vToken['value'],
}

response = requests.post('https://services.paci.gov.kw/card/search', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)
print(response.text)

with open('Output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(response.text)
```