# Use BeautifulSoup to return attribute

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get an attribute of an element but I got None for that element
Here's my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

res = requests.get('https://services.paci.gov.kw/card/inquiry?lang=ar&serviceType=2')
#print(res.text)
with open('Output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(res.text))


soup = bs(res.text, 'html.parser')
vToken = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': '__RequestVerificationToken'}, first=True)
print(vToken)
print(vToken['value'])
```

I checked the Output.txt file and I found that attribute implemented but couldn't get its attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the `first=True` argument from your `find()`, it will throw:

```
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

res = requests.get('https://services.paci.gov.kw/card/inquiry?lang=ar&serviceType=2')

soup = bs(res.text, 'html.parser')
vToken = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': '__RequestVerificationToken'})

print(vToken['value'])
```

Output:

```
CfDJ8Jg8_Y_lKLtGsMsCG9ry3AgPF3n0c5Zc7jzzJ0hYmIv2my6IqtFlABkZLpwb3f9JfCP3-Yhr_P4bvwp_jyw47G6MTcAAUx9ZBE82oSQ4tpSrJxS4vxtJj6LPZ2vaLwGDgiYitq3qYiJmNZvsg_FHOj0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So this doesn't require headers?!

Comment: It is quiet a good think to provide `headers` but not needed in this case, it is simply the `first=True` argument that should be removed.

Comment: I tried to do the same as for another element `<input type="hidden" class="servicesToken" id="Token" name="Token" value="" />` but the value here is empty while when was using the browser, there is a value related to this element. I added the headers but the same problem.

Comment: This would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus - Maybe it is generated dynamically and you have to use `selenium` instead of `requests`

Answer (score 2):

Add `headers` and there you have it:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0",
}

url = 'https://services.paci.gov.kw/card/inquiry?lang=ar&serviceType=2'
soup = bs(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, 'html.parser')
vToken = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': '__RequestVerificationToken'})
print(vToken['value'])
```

Output:

```
CfDJ8KYexE-JuUdFv8XKqnZO6wgPM1_Pmaf96y1YdvqHY2mJLJtbNiU0p4tU3xVQSudgrpBxQmINXC8dopZp6NEb3rl-GRhpmSfDrUwn8_uGnNKB6u7cHDNNNIXo-bGEH0gNz6nq4IIWfIgdDqQxl47E6vQ
```

Comment: The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71677638/return-null-json-requests-post-method is related. Can you have a look please?